# What kind of paint marker will work for flexible vinyl?

Tags: paint, medium-selection, plastic

I'm making a mini cape out of flexible vinyl, like the kind used for window clings. I need to leave light blue, permanent marks on the vinyl that won't peel or flake as the cape is flexed.

I'd really prefer a pen or marker of some kind, because I need to make designs that I am not confident I can do with a brush. The designs also need to be quite fine, like 2-3 mm max.

Is there a single type product that would work? Or would I need to use multiple products (application + sealant?). I have no idea what will actually adhere to the vinyl without smearing.

Here's a prototype of what I'm working on, for context:

[image]

As an added bonus, I've found out that the material grabs my finger prints very easily, so preferably the solution will hold up to being wiped down periodically to remove prints.

Comment: That's weird looking spiderman

Comment: @Vishwa http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0207120/

Comment: no no I'm familiar with the cartoon. I meant that figurine in first photo. he looks at me weird

Comment: @Vishwa It's the only one from that show they made. Beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: ha haa.. gotcha ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would try with a sharpie or other alcohol based marker. Look for the [industrial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IFEO) version.

As I wasn’t aware you needed colors, I didn’t recommend posca paint markers, which are acrylic-based and permanent.

What it sounds like you’re going to need to do is to clean the surface to be painted with rubbing alcohol. The apply a fine mist of plastic primer from a spray can in several light coats. You can usually find them in most automotive shops. Then apply your marker and let dry. Cover with a gloss coat of spray varnish.

One last alternative might be colored nail polish.

Comment: I found the perfect colored Sharpie, non-industrial, today, and it smears off pretty easily. I'm not finding the industrial or "Pro" in the color I need.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the sheets of colored duct tape that you could cut out the design. That should stick and flex with the vinyl.

Comment: Except it will get creases.

Comment: While a possibly viable solution, it would lead me to have to ask "how to effectively cut tape into detailed patterns" and then also how to apply it perfectly straight.